# помогите разобраться с проектом на Spring

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven, spring-boot

пытаюсь создать приложение по уроку с сайта https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/
вставляю в файл pom.xml код:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>sweater</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>


<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>serving-web-content</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>serving-web-content</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

IDEA ругается на строке spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf - not found
в чем проблема?
JDK версия 1.8,
Maven 3.3.9

Comment: В терминали **idea**  введите команду `mvn clean install`. Скорее всего зависимости не скачаны на ваш компьютер и **idea** не может их найти, поэтому подчеркивает красным

Comment: спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 1):

Судя по комментариям, ошибка была в том, что не была выполнена сборка проекта командой `mvn clean install`. Во время сборки проекта система сборки **maven** скачивает все прописанные в `dependencies` библиотеки из *maven репозитория* в локальную дирректория `.m2`.

А **intellij-idea** проверяет проект на собираемость перед запуском в фоновом режиме, и если нету подходящей библиотеки в дирректории `.m2` то начинает отсутствующую библиотеку подчеркивать красным.